# How to get most probable matching line

Tags: python, shell

I am having Text file which contains following few lines

```
1). please share the user manual and integration document
2). what is long code
3). what is short code
4). what are the long code and short code numbers
5). how to create group
```

If I give some input string for example "how I will create group" then it must have to give most matching line from file.

for the line "how I will create group" most matching line in file is "how to create group".

I know the following

```
grep 'string pattern' file
```

but this will handle single word

Comment: `most matching line` - you have to define that way, way better. Fromthe definition, your program will follow naturally. Which line is the most matching line? Try to think of edge cases, ex. which line is "most matching" to `what is short and long code` and why? Which line is the most matching to `rtalcgw  lho piouwe Ier` (this is `how I will create group` but with letters in random order)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit verbose output but you can edit for your wishes. This one uses [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html?highlight=difflib#module-difflib) to calculate similarity.

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def get_match_ratio(sentence1, sentence2):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, sentence1, sentence2).ratio()

def match(iterable, sentence):
    """returns dictionary {iterable-element: percent match with sentence}"""
    return {element: get_match_ratio(element, sentence) for element in iterable}

def ranked_match(iterable, sentence):
    """returns list of iterable-elements sorted by percent match of sentence"""
    return [element[0] for element in sorted(
        match(iterable, sentence).items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True
        )]

# That comes from the text-file
sentences = [
    '1). please share the user manual and integration document',
    '2). what is long code',
    '3). what is short code',
    '4). what are the long code and short code numbers',
    '5). how to create group',
    ]

sample = "how I will create group"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        sentence = input('Enter the sentence to approve:\n')
        results = match(sentences, sample)
        ranked = ranked_match(sentences, sample)
        print("Most matching sentence: " + ranked[0])
        # Most matching sentence: 5). how to create group

        print("Match quota: " + str(results[ranked[0]]) + "%")
        # Match quota: 0.7391304347826086%

        print("Ranked List: " + '; '.join(ranked))
        # Ranked List: 5). how to create group; 2). what is long code; 3). what is short code; 1). please share the user manual and integration document; 4). what are the long code and short code numbers

        print("Result Dictionary: ")
        # Result Dictionary: 

        print(results)
        # {'5). how to create group': 0.7391304347826086, '3). what is short code': 0.26666666666666666, '2). what is long code': 0.2727272727272727, '1). please share the user manual and integration document': 0.25, '4). what are the long code and short code numbers': 0.2222222222222222}
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to `difflib`. OP probably wanted the results in the form of a shell command, but IMHO this solution is much cleaner. Just spent the last 5 minutes reading into `difflib`. The library is incredible.

Comment: I am getting wrong result as like following few cases 1).
**User sentence:** `how to resolve ssl error`
**Most matching sentence:** `how to solve connection time out error`
**Match quota:** `0.6129032258064516%`
**Here Expected output is :** `what is ssl error how to rectify it`
2)
**User sentence:** `what is mean push sms service`
**Most matching sentence:** `what is an ussd service`
**Match quota:** `0.8461538461538461%`
**Here Expected output is :** `what are push sms services`

Like above getting error in some cases

Comment: Those are no errors. it is how difflib calculates it. Maybe you can subclass it and make it fit your needs. But that seem to be another topic.